# PowerShell Error - Method Not Found

Tags: powershell, windows-10

When using `$Computer.StartsWith("WI-")` I get the following error

```
   Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer] does not contain a method named 'StartsWith'
```

I am under the impression that this is a default method.  Is there something I have to import to use this?

Comment: `$Computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=local' -Filter '*' 

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
   if ($Computer.StartsWith("WI-"))
   {
        <#Write-Host "Moving $Computer to $TargetOU" |#> Move-ADObject $Computer -TargetPath $TargetOU
   }
} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is pretty clear: an object of  `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer]` type does not contain a method named '`StartsWith`'.

Where the `$Computer` comes from? From [`Get-ADComputer` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx)? Read [How to list all AD computer object properties](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/How_to_list_all_AD_computer_object_properties)

Running `$Computer | Get-Member | ft -AutoSize` should prompt more.

Run `$Computer.GetType()` as well. For instance, next could work if `$Computer` is not an array:

```
$Computer.Name.StartsWith("WI-")
$Computer.CN.StartsWith("WI-")
$Computer.DisplayName.StartsWith("WI-")
```

However, next similar expressions could give another results:

```
$Computer.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("WI-")
$Computer.CN.ToUpper().StartsWith("WI-")
$Computer.DisplayName.ToUpper().StartsWith("WI-")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME.StartsWith("WI-")
```

Comment: That stopped the error but my if statement is still not working.
   if ($env:COMPUTERNAME.StartsWith("WI-"))
   {
        Write-Host "Moving $Computer to $TargetOU" | Move-ADObject $Computer -TargetPath $TargetOU
   }

Comment: John, Jan answered your question. If you have another question then you should post it separately. See the Help Center for more details.

Comment: Actually, Χpẘ, No, that does not answer my question.  $env:COMPUTERNAME referes to the computer name of the machine I am using not my $Computer variable.